# Reinstating option to switch from question on iOS app to Chrome to vote for re-opening?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, vote-to-reopen

Until a week or two ago, probably the last update, I routinely used an option on the iOS app, to switch to Chrome and the browser app, so that I could perform actions like voting to re-open a question.

Looking in the same place now that option is no longer available.

[image]

Unless I was imagining it, could that option be reinstated?

Comment: Still there, just moved